# New Windows 10 Computer having Network Issues

Tags: windows-10

I recieved a new desktop computer from iBuyPower for Christmas this year, it worked great when I first got it, however, upon bringing it back home after break, the wireless adaptor refused to show any wireless networks other than one that says, "Hidden Network." It was working fine beforehand. The device manager identifies that the wireless adaptor is inside, but it refuses to connect to any wireless networks. When I troubleshoot the problem, it says that I need to connect to a network, but when I press "Show me a list of available networks," nothing happens and it skips to the next page.

Later I tried plugging in a USB Wireless Adaptor, and after some waiting, my Network finally showed up on both the Wireless Adaptors, trying to connect to the networks just led to the "Can't connect," message.

I'm not very educated with computers, but I will try to provide as much more information as I need.

Comment: in device manager, right-click and uninstall the wireless adapter. Do not click delete. Next, right-click on your computer and hit scan. Let it reinstall and try to reconnect.

Comment: I unistalled both the USB Wireless Adaptor and the built-in one, the results are still the same, the only network showing up is the "Hidden Network."

Comment: What is listed under device manager for the adapter? Also.. i like your first name..

Comment: The built-in adaptor says, "Realtek RTL8811AU Wireless LAN 802.11ac USB 2.0 Network Adaptor." The one that I later plugged in to the computer via USB is labeled, "Compact Wireless-G USB Adaptor."

Answer (score 0):

Update your wireless driver (google your computer make and model for drivers).  If that doesn't help, then you'll need to replace your WiFi card (happened to my brand new Lenovo recently).  If it happens to all wifi networks, it's either a driver, wifi card itself (check your warranty) or your wifi is turned off on your computer.

Hope this helps!